# The public type SalutonFrame must be defined in its own file

Tags: java, html

```
package achieveStrength;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SalutonFrame extends JFrame {
    public SalutonFrame () {
        super ("Salutation Mondo!");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    private void setLookAndFeel () {
        try { 
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");

        } catch (Exception exc) {
        // ignore error
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SalutonFrame frame = new SalutonFrame();
    }
}
```

In Eclipse I am receiving an error that is in the title of this question. I don't understand why this error is being thrown.  I also do not understand how a class can be accessed if it is not on the same page of code in a program.  I have some website development understanding so I may be able to create an analogy for someone who has that understanding as well.  Here it is:

My guess is that if the main method accesses a class that is not within the file that the main method is written in then the two files that are working together must be held inside of the same folder like image files are held inside of a website's folder along with the .html file that requests the use of that particular image file.  I hope this makes sense to someone out there.  I really want to understand Java in order to use it well.

Thanks in advance for any help I may receive!

Answer (score 0):

You're defining an `achieveStrength.SalutonFrame` class, it should be defined in a `SalutonFrame.java` file inside an `achieveStrength` folder which parent folder should be defined as a source folder.

For example, this is the hierarchy I would expect to find :

```
projectName/                # project root
  src/                      # source folder
    achieveStrength/        # package achieveStrength
      SalutonFrame.java     # class achieveStrength.SalutonFrame
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  That makes total sense to me.  I wonder why the book I'm learning from has the example program written exactly as I wrote it here.  Oh well, I will try this out and report back.

Comment: Okay, now I have the public class in another file and I am receiving another error that reads: "the serializable class SalutonFrame does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of long type."

Comment: Okay, now I have the public class in another file and I am receiving another error that reads: "the serializable class SalutonFrame does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of long type."  Do you have any idea what that means or how to address it?  Also, when I saved the second file with the public class as a .java the text did not respond in the way that I expected.  No color changes were made based on the type of code the text represents i.e. public changing to purple and Strings changing to blue.  Does this mean I made an error somewhere?

Comment: You can use eclipse to "quick-fix" the first error. It will add a `serialVersionUID` with a generated or default value, both are fine. For the editor maybe you can try closing the editor tab and reopening the file, but first make sure you haven't created a `SalutonFrame.java.txt` file.

Comment: Anyway it looks like my answer provided a solution to the problem you stated in your question. Could you mark it as accepted? If you have further problem you can still open other questions, but maybe you should try following a tutorial if you're lacking the basics.